# Getting a list of running processes and killing a specific process

Tags: android, process, kill-process

I'm executing the following piece of code:

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<RunningTaskInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningTasks(1000);
```

Then, I kill one process I'm interested in with

```
actvityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(process.baseActivity.getPackageName());
```

where `process` is an entry from `procInfos`.

The problem is if I run `getRunningTasks` again - it would still show the process I (presumably) killed, while a task manager for Android listed that process before calling `killBackgroundProcesses` and removed it from list after that call.

So, any ideas on how does task manager get its list of running processes? 
And is it normal that I have successfully killed 3rd-party process on an unrooted device?

Comment: This would have been better as a new question, since it's quite different from what you originally asked. In any case, you can find most of the answer to your current question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814696/how-to-kill-currently-running-task-in-android , in particular the second answer.

Comment: @RobPridham: thank you very much, I didn't see that question. And my rephrased question doesn't seem too different from the original to me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Running' doesn't mean that a user started it; it might be listening for events, doing a scheduled background sync or anything else.

ActivityManager.getRunningTasks() might be closer to what you want, but in essence you are always going to have this problem, because the user is not in full control over what is currently active.

Comment: Makes sense, but I still have no idea as to why Gallery shows up as "running" because I rebooted the device and surely didn't start Gallery at all.

Comment: Could be any number of reasons - as just one example, an application can subscribe to the system boot event, and receiving it will cause it to be started, whereupon it will count as running until the system decides to kill it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `getRunningTasks()` really seems to do what I need. One last question: do you, by chance, know how to get a corresponding process name for a task (`ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo`) returned by `getRunningTasks`?

Comment: Yes - the baseActivity property of that object will lead you to a package name, which you can match against the values in the pkgList property of the processes found in your original post.

Comment: Note that as of Android 5.0 Lollipop (API Level 21), ActivityManager.getRunningTasks() has been deprecated. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)