# Android ~ detection any other application/service

Tags: android, android-service, android-event

I know there are methods to find the running applications, services.. in Android. But is there any event to detect if any other application/service installed or unistalled?

Comment: Possible duplication of this Question?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297149/android-listen-for-app-installed-upgraded-broadcast-message

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839592/getting-a-list-of-running-processes-and-killing-a-specific-process

Comment: These links are good for me thanks;)