# How to close all background active applications?

Tags: android

I have one requirement like, I want to close all background running applications. I used this code, but its not working...

```
    ActivityManager  manager =  (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> listOfProcesses = manager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo process : listOfProcesses)
    {
        System.out.println(process.processName);
        manager.killBackgroundProcesses(process.processName);
    }
```

Any help?

Comment: Define `it's not working`.

Comment: and have you added `android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES` permission in manifest?

Comment: @GopalRao yes I added permission

Comment: You need to pass the process's package name i.e. package name of the app to which the process belongs to. not the process name...

Comment: but 'process.processName' will gives the package name only...

Comment: Android sets a process for every package so when you close the package you kill the process as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only kill your own apps, e.g. the ones running in the same process or with the same userID. You can not kill others, unless the device is rooted.

have a look at this answer. [How to kill  currently running task in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814696/how-to-kill-currently-running-task-in-android/8849562#8849562)

**Your problem will be solved now**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    PackageManager pm;
    pm = getPackageManager();
    // get a list of installed apps.
    packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        if ((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1)
            continue;
        if (packageInfo.packageName.equals("mypackage"))
            continue;
        mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageInfo.packageName);
    }
```

Comment: Its not working Suresh... I am running mediaplayer in background & used your code... Its is not closing..