# How to programmatically force quit (or temporarily disable) Google App

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-package-managers, android-4.3-jelly-bean, google-now

Is there a way to force-quit [Google App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox&hl=en) (AKA `Google Search`) from my app?

If so, how to do that?

Comment: Probably duplicated with this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12037227/2104879

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you will need ActivityManager's killBackgroundProcesses():

```
  public static void killOtherPackage(Context ctx) {
        if (ctx != null) {      
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) ctx.getSystemService(ctx.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (am != null)
            am.killBackgroundProcesses("com.comp.prodline.specificpack");
        }

  }
```

Plus android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES in the manifest.

But I doubt that you will succeed killing Google's app.

More on this can be found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814696/how-to-kill-currently-running-task-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```