# Any way to close recent apps in code?

Tags: java, android, task

I want to build upon my battery saving android app and add the functionality to close all apps excluding user-specified ones.

Im not asking how to kill a process, I want to close the recent apps in the same way that you would by hitting your recent apps button and swiping them all away.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: You can only kill your own apps. You can not kill other apps unless the device is rooted. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814696/how-to-kill-currently-running-task-in-android/8849562#8849562).

Comment: @JayB:Let me know the below answer is helps you or not?

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommanded but it is posible by using **killBackgroundProcesses** of **Activitymanager**.

```
    List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    PackageManager pm;
    pm = getPackageManager();
    //get a list of all installed apps.
    packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

    ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

   for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
        if((packageInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM)==1)continue;
        if(packageInfo.packageName.equals("mypackage")) continue;
        mActivityManager.killBackgroundProcesses(packageInfo.packageName);
   }
```

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: @JayB:Let me know if this answer is helps you or not.