# How to stop another android application programmatically which is running in backgraound? Without Root

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing an android app which will display list of all the installed app in mobile.

I'm already listed all the app which are installed in my phone, and trying to stop a app from list.

**I want to stop a app from list by one click.** ***Without Root***

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For that first you have to get process ID of that particular app which is listed and running. After kill that process from that process ID.

Comment: How to get PID of particular app?

Comment: Try to search on google related to ActivityManager concept. You will get your answer.

Comment: For your reference understand this http://androidbite.blogspot.com/2013/07/android-display-running-application.html

Comment: You can't. Unless you have a rooted device or your app has system permissions.

Answer (score -2):

You can only kill your own apps, for example, the apps which are running in the same process or with the same userID. You can not kill others, unless the device is rooted.

Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814696/how-to-kill-currently-running-task-in-android/8849562#8849562) to know about **killing background processes** of app.

Comment: I want to stop app not process.

Comment: sure, you can kill background processes of other apps as well. The other apps will automatically be stoped once you killed their processes. Have a look at the documentation of killBackgroundProcesses(): https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#killBackgroundProcesses(java.lang.String) . You can use this from API  level 8 and up